# What am I doing wrong here? Calculate the line integral of $f(x,y,z) = xe^{yz}$ from $(4,2,3)$ to $(0,0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

On the one hand, I should be able to calculate the integral from $(0,0,0)$ to $(4,2,3)$ and multiply that answer by negative one.

Parameterize the line as $r(t) = (4t,2t,3t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  Then the line integral is $$\int_0^1 4te^{6t^2}\sqrt{29} dt = \frac{ \sqrt{29}}{3} \int_0^6 e^u du = \frac{\sqrt{29}}{3}(e^6-1)$$ So the answer I'm looking for is $\frac{\sqrt{29}}{3}(1-e^6)$.  On the other hand, suppose I parameterized the line directly from $(4,2,3)$ to $(0,0,0)$, as $r(t) = (-4t + 4, -2t+2, -3t+3)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  Then the line integral is $$\int_0^1 (-4t+4)e^{(-2t+2)(-3t+3)}\sqrt{29}dt = -4\sqrt{29} \int_0^1(t-1)e^{6t^2-12t+6}dt$$ Substitute $u = 6t^2-12t+6$ to get $du = (12t-12)dt$, so the integral is $$\frac{-\sqrt{29}}{3} \int_6^0 e^u du = \frac{-\sqrt{29}}{3}(1 - e^6)$$ Isn't this the negative of the answer I should get?

Comment: But isn't the parameterization $r(t) = (-4t+4,-2t+2,-3t+3)$, $t$ going from $0$ to $1$, a path from $(4,2,3)$ to $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Since the value of the line integral is independent of the parametrization (as long as the curve is only traced out once), the answer of $\frac{\sqrt{29}}{3}(e^6-1)$ obtained from both parametrizations is correct.

Comment: I thought if $f$ was a continuous function given on a path from $P$ to $Q$, and the path is parameterized by $r(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t)), 0 \leq t \leq 1$, $r(0) = P$ and $r(1) = Q$, then the line integral from $P$ to $Q$ is $$\int_0^1 f(x(t),y(t),z(t))\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2}dt$$ Didn't I follow this formula exactly in the second integral I calculated?  I still got negative of the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what folks are trying to say is that, in this case (since the curve is being traced out exactly one time) the line integral will be independent of the parametrization of the curve.

That is, it shouldn't matter if you go from (0,0,0) to (4,2,3) or (4,2,3) to (0,0,0) as long as you follow that formula, you will get the same answer WITHOUT having to multiply by a negative.

So $$\int_0^1 4te^{6t^2}\sqrt{29} dt = \frac{ \sqrt{29}}{3} \int_0^6 e^u du = \frac{\sqrt{29}}{3}(e^6-1)$$

and

$$\int_0^1 (-4t+4)e^{(-2t+2)(-3t+3)}\sqrt{29}dt = -4\sqrt{29} \int_0^1(t-1)e^{6t^2-12t+6}dt=\frac{-\sqrt{29}}{3} \int_6^0 e^u du = \frac{-\sqrt{29}}{3}(1 - e^6)=\frac{\sqrt{29}}{3}(e^6-1)$$

are both valid ways of calculating the integral.

Note that this works because you're working with a line integral over a scalar field.

If you check out pg. 3; Remark 1, it might be clearer. 
https://people.math.osu.edu/kwa.1/254au10/16.2withScannedExamples.pdf